# Rails materialize-sass form with autocomplete and cocoon gem nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, material-design, cocoon-gem

I am using [materialize-sass](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass) gem on a form. Using autocomplete feature to get Vendor names. other fields on the form are item names and quantity which are a nested resource. For this I am using [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem

For some reason the very first time the page loads, all seems to work fine. But adding more fields does not seem to be working. I tried using drop down select and that does not show the list of items. I replaced it with another autocomplete and the main field does show however the auto complete feature does not work. Any idea what may be wrong?

Please see my code below.

purchase_orders _forms.html.erb

```html
<div class="col s12">
 <%= simple_form_for(@purchase_order) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col s6">
   <%= f.input :vendor_name, input_html: { class: 'vendor_name autocomplete' } %>
  </div>
 </div>
 <section class="show-section">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col l12"><h4>Item List</h4></div>
   <div class="col s12">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :purchase_order_details do |purchase_order_detail| %>
    <%= render 'purchase_order_detail_fields', :f => purchase_order_detail %>
    <div class="links">
     <%= link_to_add_association 'Add More', f, :purchase_order_details %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

_purchase_order_detail_fields.html.erb

```html
<div class="nested-fields">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col l6">
   <%#= f.input(:item_id, collection: Ingredient.is_active, label_method: :title, value_method: :id) %>
   <%= f.input :item_name, input_html: { class: 'item_name autocomplete' } %>
  </div>
  <div class="col l5">
   <%= f.input :item_quantity %>
  </div>
  <div class="col l1">
   <%= link_to_remove_association "delete", f, :class => "material-icons teal-text text-lighten-1" %>
  </div>
  <%#= f.hidden_field :item_type , :value=> params[:category_id] %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have also tried to use the callback to re initialize materializeForm but that does not seem to be working either.

Comment: Upon further investigation the callback is the way to solve the issue. I will be posting the answer as a coffee script I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the coffee script I used to be able to populate the autocompelte

```js
$.ajax
  url: '/packing_materials/by_name.json'
  dataType: 'json'
  success: (my_res) ->
    $ ->
      $('input.packing_material_name.autocomplete').autocomplete data: my_res

$(document).on 'cocoon:before-insert', ->
  $.ajax
    url: '/packing_materials/by_name.json'
    dataType: 'json'
    success: (my_res) ->
      $ ->
        $('input.packing_material_name.autocomplete').autocomplete data: my_res
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking out the demo-project they use, and more specifically the [init.js](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-rails/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/init.coffee) they use I notice two things: if you are using turbolinks you will have to do the same, and when using cocoon you will have to do something like:

```
$('form').on('cocoon:before-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
  $(insertedItem).find('select').material_select();
})
```

Comment: i used the call back for sure but the code needed was through ajax so the solution was a bit different.