# Materialize CSS Select with Cocoon Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize, cocoon-gem

I have a problem, in Rails I'm using Cocoon for nested forms and Materialize CSS for my front-end framework.

With a select function, one needs to add the following code for the Select to be displayed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

It works with normal forms, but when the nested fields are added, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: One solution is to change the class to "browser-default" - but you lose the Materialize style... Any workaround would be appreciated!

Comment: Identical question to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235870/rails-materialize-sass-form-with-autocomplete-and-cocoon-gem-nested-resource/47267968

Comment: You can try window.materializeForm.init() in the call back. it should work.